# wait for async function with $.each before continuing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made [this fiddle to help debug](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/652320/) the following code...

If you go to the fiddle and keep hitting "run" - you will notice that the results are different every time (they should be the same). I am trying to accomplish 2 thing

1. how can i make sure that the `year` key/val is on `items[]` every time — it is not consistent now.
2. I do not want to alter `titles` during `transformData()`. As it is now the array is being modified... my attempt was `transformData(titles.slice(0), items => {` but it is still being altered.

   ```
   const titles = [
       { title: 'avatar' },
       { title: 'jurassic' },
       { title: 'black panther' }
   ];

   transformData(titles.slice(0), items => {
       const problem = items.length !== titles.length;
       const debugg ={
           problem: problem,
           counts: {
               items: items.length, // echos 2
               titles: titles.length // echos 3
           },
           items: items, // echos an object with 3 arrays inspector shows length:3
           titles: titles // echos an object with 3 arrays inspector shows length:3
       };
       console.log('debugg', debugg)
       $('pre').text(JSON.stringify(debugg, null, 2))

   });

   function transformData(configs, next) {
       const self = this;
       const items = [];
       const last = configs.length;
       $.each(configs, function(i, config) {
           items.push(config);
           $.ajax({
               url: 'https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=f4e09aec&&t=' + items[i].title,
               type: 'GET',
               crossDomain: true,
               dataType: 'jsonp',
               success: function(results) {
                   if (results.Response != 'False') {
                       console.log(results);
                       items[i].year = results.Year;
                       if (i+1 === last) { next(items); }
                   }
               }
           });
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: This is an old problem called race condition. Because of the nature of asynchronism, you cannot be sure of the order the calls results will get back in. You need to do each of them in order, I would suggers by `await`ing them (use JS's `async/await` syntax) or `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ushzewg/).
The reason your `titles` was getting updated, because `titles` array and array passed as arguments had reference to same objects. Instead of pushing same object, i'm creating new objects,

```
items.push({...config})
```

```js
const titles = [
    { title: 'avatar' },
    { title: 'jurassic' },
    { title: 'black panther' }
];

transformData(titles.slice(0), items => {
    const problem = items.length !== titles.length;
    const debugg ={
        problem: problem,
        counts: {
            items: items.length, // echos 2
            titles: titles.length // echos 3
        },
        items: items, // echos an object with 3 arrays inspector shows length:3
        titles: titles // echos an object with 3 arrays inspector shows length:3
    };
    console.log('debugg', debugg)
    $('pre').text(JSON.stringify(debugg, null, 2))
        
});



function transformData(configs, next) {
    const self = this;
    const items = [];
    const last = configs.length;
    const p = []
    $.each(configs, function(i, config){
     items.push({...config})
     p.push($.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=f4e09aec&&t=' + items[i].title,
            type: 'GET',
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'jsonp'
        }))
    })
    
    Promise.all(p).then((values)=>{
   for(var i =0;i<values.length;i++){
       items[i].year = values[i].Year
      }
      next(items)
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: This looks promising (get it?)... Gonna try it soon.